# Exponential PDF Mystery

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, envelope

The envelope function of the family of exponential PDFs of the form

$$f_\lambda(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$

is

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{ex}$$

for $x > 0, \lambda > 0$. The point of tangency between $f_\lambda(x)$ and $g(x)$ is

$$\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}, \frac{\lambda}{e}\right)$$

Now suppose that $X$ is an exponentially distributed random variable with a PDF equal to $f_\lambda(x)$. Then

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$$

My question is this: why is the $x$ coordinate of the point of tangency between $f_\lambda(x)$ and $g(x)$ equal to $E[X]$?

Visualization: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uhllhcd5um

Note: The same pattern holds for a Continuous Poisson PDF, though it does not hold for some other PDFs that I checked (such as the Half-Normal distribution,  the Gumbel Distribution, and the Lomax distribution).

Visualization: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gk2uwaikz2

**EDIT:**

The Gamma Distribution obeys this rule as well:

Visualization: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0ix5es6pqu

**EDIT #2:**

The Chi Squared Distribution obeys this rule as well, as a consequence of being a special case of the Gamma distribution. Also, since the exponential distribution is a special case of the Gamma distribution as well it is not surprising that it obeys this rule. However, the continuous Poisson distribution is not a special case of the Gamma distribution, yet it obeys the rule, which is yet to be explained (as is the reason why the Gamma distribution obeys the rule in the first place).

Visualization: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oe9sg3mf1q

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by an "envelope function"? And also a "Continuous Poisson pdf" for that matter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)
https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/maximum-value-of-a-poisson-distribution-4327

Comment: I have included a visualization of what I am talking about.

Comment: Could be a coincidence? Have you tried envelopes of other families?

Comment: Coincidences don't exist in math insofar as exact equalities are concerned. I have tried the envelope of a family of continuous Poisson PDFs and it works as well (see my visualization above).

Comment: Ordinarily, it would be silly to answer a question "why are these two things equal" with "because when you compute them you get $1/\lambda$ for both." In this case, though, such answers are the only justification I can see for your general claim that "coincidences don't exist in math insofar as exact equalities are concerned." If you reject such silly answers, then I'd be inclined to agree with the comment of @Kusma "could be a coincidence."

Comment: I'm willing to at least suppose that there is some kind of underlying principle at work here which allows some subset of PDFs to have this property. If such a principle exists then this is no longer a coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

So the point of tangency is defined by the adjacency of the nearby distributions to first order, $$f_{\lambda+d\lambda}(x) \approx f_\lambda(x),$$
which we can just solve:$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\big(\lambda ~e^{-\lambda x}\big) = (1 - \lambda x)~e^{-\lambda x} = 0~~~\Rightarrow~~~1 - \lambda x = 0~~~\Rightarrow~~~x = 1/\lambda.$$
Note that if we use a slightly different definition of the parameter, say $\lambda = \lambda(y)$ for some other parameter $y,$ we would still come up with $x=1/\lambda(y)$ due to the chain rule and dividing out the resulting $\frac{d\lambda}{dy}$ term in our $\partial/\partial y$ derivative. So for a given one-parameter distribution this is a robust finding with respect to that parameter -- if it holds for one parametrization it should hold for others.

With that said, it does seem roughly coincidental: the parameters used to describe a family of things seem very different from the things themselves. Can we use that to build a counterexample?

## Shifting normals

One possibility: consider $s\mapsto \operatorname{Normal}(s, s^2),$ the subset of normal distributions whose standard deviations are equal to their means. Their PDFs are of course, $$f_s(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x - s)^2}{2s^2}\right)$$ with mean $s$ and standard deviation $s$. But after a bit of work, $${\partial f_s\over\partial s} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x - s)^2}{2s^2}\right)\left({s^2 + s x - x^2\over s^3}\right),$$ which is equal to zero when $x = \phi~s,$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. Of course the golden ratio is not $1$ and thus we do not have $x = E[X]$ as desired.

Just to prove visually that this is indeed the proper envelope, here is a mock-up I built out of your existing demos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/stkuixtk8o , with $y=f_{x/\phi}(x)$ as the envelope.

Now there is an interesting thing here because that expression *does* have *two* roots which *sum* to the mean value; the other root is $x = (1-\phi) s.$ Can we get rid of that, too?

## Half-normals

The half normal distribution is defined using the standard normal PDF $n(x)$ as $$h_s(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{2~n(x/s)}{s} & \text{if } x > 0,\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Here $s$ is no longer the standard deviation but is just a parameter.

Working it out, I believe $${\partial h_s \over \partial s} = \frac{2~n(x/s)}{s}\left(\frac{x^2 -s^2}{s^3}\right),$$ and thus on the envelope, $x = s$. But that is not the mean of this distribution, which [Wikipedia lists as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) $s~\sqrt{2/\pi}.$

Comment: One can then ask the following question: what are necessary and/or sufficient conditions for a PDF with one or more free parameters to have this property? I have already identified the continuous approximation to the discrete Poisson PDF as possessing this property as well. Are there any other such PDFs? What form do they need to have?

Comment: Well I mean we can formally state what you want by using subscript numbers for "the partial derivative with respect to the $n^\text{th}$ argument." Then what you are looking for is the family of singly-parametrized PDFs $(\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb R,\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R, f: \Lambda\times\Omega\to(0,1))$ such that $$f_1\left(\lambda, \int_\Omega dx~x~f(\lambda, x)\right) = 0.$$With that said I don't see any really slick ways to solve for that, but maybe you can write, say, a cumulant expansion for $f$ and what that looks like for $f_1$ and find something worthwhile?